# How to adjust ASA Failover Times?

Tags: cisco-asa, failover

I want to adjust my failover poll timing.
[image]

The proposed column is what I am wanting to set it up as.
I believe the following commands will obtain what I want from the first two rows but Im not sure how to adjust the remaining.

```
failover polltime unit msec 500 holdtime 2
failover polltime interface msec 400 holdtime 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your commands both fall outside of the "minimum" range allowed by ASA. If you see your table above it says 800, 500 but you have specified 500, 400. I do not think these will work, which is probably why you are having trouble.

As for the other settings, set them accordingly - `failover polltime [setting] msec 2000 holdtime 10`. Hold time must be >= 5 msec.

Comment: I thought my commands would make the unit fail time 1 second and interface 800ms (polltime x hold time)?